# RoutingSlipActivityCompleted not trigger

Tags: masstransit

I added a consumer to observe routing slip events, but doesn't work as expected. `RoutingSlipCompleted` consumer is always triggered, `RoutingSlipActivityCompleted` and  `RoutingSlipActivityFaulted` consumer are never triggered. This is my consumer code.

```cs
public abstract class RoutingSlipExecuteActivityResponseProxy<TRequest, TResponse, TFaultResponse> :
    IConsumer<RoutingSlipActivityCompleted>,
    IConsumer<RoutingSlipActivityFaulted>,
    IConsumer<RoutingSlipCompleted>
    where TRequest : class
    where TResponse : class
    where TFaultResponse : class
{
    public abstract string ActivityName { get; }
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<RoutingSlipActivityCompleted> context)
    {
        if(context.Message.ActivityName!= ActivityName)
        {
            return;
        }
        var request = context.Message.GetVariable<TRequest>("Request");
        var requestId = context.Message.GetVariable<Guid>("RequestId");

        Uri responseAddress = null;
        if (context.Message.Variables.ContainsKey("ResponseAddress"))
            responseAddress = context.Message.GetVariable<Uri>("ResponseAddress");

        if (responseAddress == null)
            throw new ArgumentException($"The response address could not be found for the faulted routing slip: {context.Message.TrackingNumber}");

        var endpoint = await context.GetResponseEndpoint<TResponse>(responseAddress, requestId).ConfigureAwait(false);

        var response = await CreateResponseMessage(context, request);

        await endpoint.Send(response).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<RoutingSlipActivityFaulted> context)
    {
        if (context.Message.ActivityName != ActivityName)
        {
            return;
        }
        var request = context.Message.GetVariable<TRequest>("Request");
        var requestId = context.Message.GetVariable<Guid>("RequestId");

        Uri faultAddress = null;
        if (context.Message.Variables.ContainsKey("FaultAddress"))
            faultAddress = context.Message.GetVariable<Uri>("FaultAddress");
        if (faultAddress == null && context.Message.Variables.ContainsKey("ResponseAddress"))
            faultAddress = context.Message.GetVariable<Uri>("ResponseAddress");

        if (faultAddress == null)
            throw new ArgumentException($"The fault/response address could not be found for the faulted routing slip: {context.Message.TrackingNumber}");

        var endpoint = await context.GetFaultEndpoint<TResponse>(faultAddress, requestId).ConfigureAwait(false);

        var response = await CreateFaultedResponseMessage(context, request, requestId);

        await endpoint.Send(response).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    protected abstract Task<TResponse> CreateResponseMessage(ConsumeContext<RoutingSlipActivityCompleted> context, TRequest request);

    protected abstract Task<TFaultResponse> CreateFaultedResponseMessage(ConsumeContext<RoutingSlipActivityFaulted> context, TRequest request, Guid requestId);

    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<RoutingSlipCompleted> context)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

My activity has no additional configuration, basically it is written according to the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to [check out this sample](https://github.com/steliyan/Sample-MT-RoutingSlipRequestResponse), which uses the `RequestResponseProxy` to handle a request via routing slip, and then generates the response based upon the RoutingSlipCompleted/RoutingSlipFaulted events.

Comment: Can I generates the response based upon the special activity RoutingSlipActivityCompleted events ?  I create a Custom RequestResponseProxy Implemented the IConsumer <RoutingSlipActivityCompleted> interface, but this RoutingSlipActivityCompleted event seems to have never been received.

Comment: Going off an activity completed, vs the entire routing slip, seems to be the wrong approach, imho.

Comment: Because I don't need to wait for all activities to complete, I just need to let the first activity complete, the request can return, and the subsequent activities can run asynchronously.Can I not realize this idea, or may encounter some unpredictable problems？

Comment: You should be able to get the activity completed event, not sure why you don't. It's published, and all the tests verify that it is indeed published. You'll likely want to check the logs.